# First Hibernate Class having Annotation

Tags: mysql, hibernate

[Image contains the JARS files which I already have.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqjPp.png)This is my hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="connecton.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_db</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is my DTO class

```
package com.app.hibernate;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "paytm_table")

public class PaytmDTO implements Serializable 
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="mob_num")
    private int mobileNumber;

    @Column(name="amount")
    private int amount;

    @Column(name="email_id")
    private String emailId;

    @Column(name="OTP")
    private int OTP;

    public PaytmDTO() {

    }

    public int getMobileNumber() {
        return mobileNumber;
    }

    public void setMobileNumber(int mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    public int getOTP() {
        return OTP;
    }

    public void setOTP(int oTP) {
        OTP = oTP;
    }

}
```

This is my DAO class

```
package com.app.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class PaytmDAO 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //Create Object of DTO
        PaytmDTO dto=new PaytmDTO();

        //Set the DTO values using Setter method
        dto.setAmount(239);
        dto.setEmailId("impriyank95@gmail.com");
        dto.setMobileNumber(941478859);
        dto.setOTP(8965);

        //Create Object of Configuration
        Configuration config=new Configuration();
        config.configure();
        config.addAnnotatedClass(PaytmDTO.class);

        //Create object of 2nd Component SessionFactory
        SessionFactory sf=config.buildSessionFactory();

        //Get a Session (3rd Component)
        Session sess=sf.openSession();
        sess.save(dto);

        Transaction tx=sess.beginTransaction();
        tx.commit();

    }

}
```

And I am getting these errors in Console

```
Jan 08, 2017 11:37:33 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at com.app.hibernate.PaytmDAO.main(PaytmDAO.java:27)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling DriverManager#getConnection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverManagerConnectionCreator.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:19)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_db
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverManagerConnectionCreator.java:34)
    ... 29 more
```

Please explain me where i am lacking? My DB username and password is root. This is my First Hibernate program and also I have paste all the jars under my lib and also done with buildPath.

Answer (score 0):

It says pretty clear

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found...

You are probably missing MySQL connector library. If you are using maven, add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.5</version> <!-- or whatever version is suitable -->
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

to your `pom.xml`. If not, you can still download the .jar from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/6.0.5)

Comment: ** I have added MySQL connector. I have attached the added JARS which are present under lib folder.**

Comment: I have added an image of my jars. Please have a look.